# mysql составление select для поиска по нескольким тэгам

Tags: python, mysql, join, pymysql, type-error

Вечер добрый, я тут новенький! просьба камнями не закидывать) Мне необходима помощь в составлении селекта для поиска записей по нескольким тэгам как с условием И так и с ИЛИ, с этим я более менее разобрался.
mysql 5.6.45
python 3

```
SELECT col1 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id 
JOIN table2 t2 
WHERE t3.id = (список id) 
GROUP by col1 DESC 
ORDER BY COUNT(t3.id)
```

Остался не решенным вопрос, как запихнуть в этот селект список тэгов, понимаю что это просто, но голова отказывается думать

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT col1 FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id JOIN table3 t3 WHERE t2.idTag IN VALUES(%s) GROUP by col1 ORDER BY COUNT(t2.id) DESC",tupleIdTag)
```

думал что подойдёт конструкция такого типа,но здесь я так понял неверно составлено, так как добавление списка tupleIdTag с несколькими значениями приводит к ошибке

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Видел другую конструкцию вида

```
SELECT A.row_id, A.name FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON (B.table_a_id = A.row_id)
WHERE B.status_id = 1 OR B.status_id = 2
GROUP BY A.row_id, A.name
HAVING SUM(1) = 2
```

Но непонятно как сделать абстрактную версию данного запроса?

Единственное что приходит в голову это создание словаря с разным количеством OR и выбор по длине входящего списка с тэгами, не знаю насколько это верно

```
`dictionary = {'1': '   SELECT A.row_id, A.name FROM A
                        INNER JOIN B ON (B.table_a_id = A.row_id)
                        WHERE B.status_id = list[0]
                        GROUP BY A.row_id, A.name',
               '2': '   SELECT A.row_id, A.name FROM A
                        INNER JOIN B ON (B.table_a_id = A.row_id)
                        WHERE B.status_id = list[0] or B.status_id = list[1]
                        GROUP BY A.row_id, A.name',
               '3': '   SELECT A.row_id, A.name FROM A
                        INNER JOIN B ON (B.table_a_id = A.row_id)
                        WHERE B.status_id = list[0] OR B.status_id = list[1]
                        OR B.status_id = list[2]
                        GROUP BY A.row_id, A.name',
               '4': '   и т.п.'}`
```

Comment: Версия MySQL хотя бы какая?

Comment: 5.6.45 извиняюсь что не указал сразу

Comment: Скорее всего нужно в `values` перечислить параметры, что есть в `tupleIdTag`, например если в `tupleIdTag` 3 значения, то: `VALUES(%s, %s, %s)`

Comment: тогда тоже необходим словарь для выбора количества значений по длине списка тэгов?

Comment: Передаёте в запрос массив тегов как одно значение строкового типа в формате CSV (т.е. сливаете массив в строку с разделителем запятая), а для отбора используете не `WHERE t2.idTag IN VALUES(%s)`, a `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t2.idTag, %s)`. Если в значениях тегов присутствует запятая - плохо, придётся и в нём, и в значении поля заменить запятую на какой-то другой символ...

Comment: @Akina WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t2.idTag, %s) ваше предложение выручило меня. Но как быть с  and? рыть информацию по having? или есть другой способ? FIND_IN_SET заменяет OR для моих задач

Comment: *Но как быть с and?* В Вашем вопросе комбинация символов `AND` вообще не обнаружена.

Comment: @Akina в связи с неопытностью, в тексте выше вообще много каши. Но мне необходимо разделить селект на два отдельных запроса, где в одном я получаю конечный результат с или(в данном случае FIND_IN_SET даёт мне это) и конечный результат со строгим вхождением тэгов где должен так или иначе использоваться AND.

Comment: Тогда рекомендую: 1) Создать новый вопрос, чётко сформулировав ОДНУ задачу 2) Максимально продумать текст вопроса - учтите, что отвечающий знает только то, что Вы напишете 3) Забыть про питон, решать задачу ТОЛЬКО в рамках SQL - потом. когда решите, перенесёте в питон 4) Предоставить - CREATE TABLE всех участвующих таблиц, INSERT INTO тестовых данных, таблично показать эталонный результат (или несколько наборов "входные условия-результат") на именно таких данных.